# Nested datatype for square matrices

Tags: haskell, types, nested

I am trying to understand how this datatype (Square) represents square matrices.

```
type Square = Square' Nil
data Square' t a = Zero (t (t a) ) | Succ (Square' (Cons t) a)
data Nil a = Nil
data Cons t a = Cons a (t a)
```

So. What is `t` here? I suppose it is one of the types declared above. 
I decided to start with the simplest, so

```
Zero (Nil (Nil Int))
```

If I put integer 4 as a value, is this a matrix `(4)`?

Suppose it is something. Now, what is this:

```
Succ ( Zero (Cons t) a)
```

if I am right about `t`, then this, perhaps, must represent some 2×2 matrix, but what are its values?

```
Succ (Zero (Cons Nil) a)
```

I would appreciate your help in my understanding of how it is a square matrix.

Comment: `t` is a type constructor that takes a type and returns a type. So `Nil` is a candidate here. If you say `Square' t a`, you will indeed construct a `Zero (Nil (Nil Int))`

Comment: You will likely enjoy Okasaki's paper, [From fast exponentiation to square matrices: an adventure in types](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=25088B69E37CE0B8357F9AD7FCD6C162?doi=10.1.1.456.357).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's introduce some informal notation to guide intuition. Write `T :> U` to denote that `T` is a sum type having one or more subcases, and `U` is one of them (at least modulo some isomorphism). We'll also use `=` between types to denote isomorphism.

So, by definition, we have

```
Square a = Square' Nil a
:> { taking the Zero branch }
Nil (Nil a)
=
()
```

So, this case denotes the empty "0x0" matrix.

```
Square a = Square' Nil a
:> { taking the Succ branch }
Square' (Cons Nil) a
:> { taking the Zero branch }
Cons Nil (Cons Nil a)
=  { def of Cons }
(Cons Nil a, Nil (Cons Nil a))
=  { def of Cons }
((a, Nil a), Nil (Cons Nil a))
=  { def of Nil }
((a, ()), ())
=
a
```

So, this is the 1x1 matrix.

```
Square a = Square' Nil a
:> { taking the Succ branch }
Square' (Cons Nil) a
:> { taking the Succ branch again }
Square' (Cons (Cons Nil)) a
:> { taking the Zero branch }
Cons (Cons Nil) (Cons (Cons Nil) a)
=
Cons (Cons Nil) (a, Cons Nil a)
=
Cons (Cons Nil) (a, a, Nil a)
=
Cons (Cons Nil) (a, a, ())
=
Cons (Cons Nil) (a, a)
=
((a,a), Cons Nil (a, a))
=
((a,a), (a,a), Nil (a, a))
=
((a,a), (a,a), ())
=
((a,a), (a,a))
```

So, this is the 2x2 matrix.

We should now be able to spot some pattern. Taking the `Succ` branches, we end up with a type of the form

```
Square' (Cons (Cons (Cons (...(Cons Nil))))) a
```

Which becomes, with the final `Zero`,

```
F (F a)
  where F = (Cons (Cons (Cons (...(Cons Nil)))))
```

Note that we considered all possible cases, so the final type must indeed be of the form `F (F a)` with some `F` of the form above.

Now, one can see that `F a` is isomorphic to `(a,a,a,....)` where the number N of `a`s it exactly the number N of `Cons`es in the definition of `F`. Hence, `F (F a)` will produce a square matrix (an N-tuple of N-tuples = square matrix).

Let's prove that by induction on the number of `Cons`es. For the zero case, we have `F = Nil`, and indeed, as we wanted, zero `a`s appear:

```
Nil a = ()
```

For the induction case, assume `F a` with N `Cons`es is `(a,a,...)` with N `a`s. The N+1 case to prove would state that `(Cons F) a` is `(a,a,...,a)`, having N+1 `a`s. Indeed:

```
Cons F a
=
(a, F a)
=
(a, (a,a....))   { 1 + N a's , as wanted }
```

QED.

Comment: What QED stands for?

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero Latin "quod erat demonstrandum" lit. "that which was to be shown". Used to terminate mathematical proofs, acting basically as a formal "there you have it". In modern use, it often has a humorous tinge to it.

Comment: Thank you @chi , now I get it on the theoretical level! On the practical one, I still have some doubts. Is this `m` from  `let m = Succ (Succ (Zero ( Cons (Cons Nil 1) 2) 3) 4)` a matrix `((1,2)(3,4))` ?

Comment: @arryn No, that would be a type error. It's easier if you define a row at a time. `let row1 = Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)` and then `let row2 = Cons 3 (Cons 4 Nil)` and finally `let m = Succ (Succ (Zero (Cons row1 (Cons row2 Nil))))`.