# Functor for square matrices

Tags: haskell, types, nested, functor

In my previous question here ([Nested datatype for square matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57918937/nested-datatype-for-square-matrices)) a datatype `Square` has been introduced. Now I want to write a functor instance for it. So I begin with map functions for all the four types. I have managed to do so for `Nil` and `Cons`:

```
mapNil :: ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> (Nil (a -> b) -> Nil a -> Nil b )
mapNil map f Nil = Nil


mapCons :: (forall b . ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> (t (a -> b) -> t a -> t b))
        -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
        -> ((Cons t (a -> b)) -> Cons t a -> Cons t b)
mapCons mapT mapA (Cons f consf) (Cons x consx) =  Cons (mapA f x) (mapT mapA consf consx)
```

Now, the `Square'` type:

```
mapSquare' :: (forall b . ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> (t (a -> b) -> t a -> t b))
           -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
           -> ((Square' t (a -> b)) -> Square' t a -> Square' t b)
mapSquare' mapT mapA (Zero fs) (Zero xs) = Zero (mapT (mapT mapA) fs xs) -- it is wrong
mapSquare' mapT mapA (Succ fs) (Succ xs) = mapSquare' (mapCons mapT) mapA fs xs
```

And then I will do something like this:

```
mapSquare = ...

-- this is, actually, the final goal:
instance Functor Square where
fmap = mapSquare
```

So far, for my `mapSquare'` Haskell says this:

```
• Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ t a
  Expected type: (a -> t b) -> a -> t b
    Actual type: t (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
• In the first argument of ‘mapT’, namely ‘(mapT mapA)’
  In the first argument of ‘Zero’, namely ‘(mapT (mapT mapA) fs xs)’
  In the expression: Zero (mapT (mapT mapA) fs xs)
```

My plan was that `(mapT mapA)` would "lift" it all between `(t (t a))` and `(t a)` levels. What is my mistake? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I have accidentally deleted the previous version of this very same question and this is a bit updated version

Comment: You can not use `mapSquare` since that type is too restrictive. The `fmap` function takes type `(c -> d) -> Square c -> Square d` here.

Comment: You `map`s look more like `(<*>)`s (so *sequential applications*) at first sight: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't think it should. I must have messed up with all the type declarations

Comment: but your `mapSquare'` takes *two* `Square' ...`s as input. An `fmap` takes a function `a -> b`, and a single "functor object" `f a`. So something really looks incorrect here.

Comment: What are `Nil` and `Cons`? (Looking at the previous question, why are they seperate types instead of data constructors for a *single* type?)

Comment: @chepner I am not sure, but I think it has something to do with the necessity of `Square` to be defined in an eta-reduced form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use `mapSquare` since that type is too restrictive. A functor has type `fmap :: Functor f => (c -> d) -> f c -> f d`. But `((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> (Square (a -> b)) -> Square a -> Square b` would only cover a subset of that. Your `mapSquare'` looks more like a "*sequential application*" [**`(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-). Notice that a `(<*>)` takes two `f x` items, not one, like the `fmap` does.

If you want to declare `Square` an instance of `Functor`, it is likely, depending on the way you implement it, that `Nil` and `Const` needs to be an instance of `Functor` as well. We can easily make these an instance of `Functor`:

```
instance Functor Nil where
    fmap _ Nil = Nil

instance Functor t => Functor (Cons t) where
    fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (fmap f xs)
```

Now we can make `Square'` an instance of `Functor` with:

```
instance Functor t => Functor (Square' t) where
    fmap f (Zero x) = Zero (fmap (fmap f) x)
    fmap f (Succ x) = Succ (fmap f x)
```

You actually do not generate those yourself. You can use the [**`DeriveFunctor`** [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveFunctor) compiler option, and let the compiler derive the functions for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Square' t a = Zero (t (t a) ) | Succ (Square' (Cons t) a) deriving Functor
data Nil a = Nil deriving Functor
data Cons t a = Cons a (t a) deriving Functor
```

This will construct the functors specified as here discussed.

Comment: Why exactly do you mean by "too restrictive"?

Comment: @arryn: initially your `mapSquare` function has type `((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> Square a -> Square b`, If I've seen that correctly, but then you thus force `c` and `d` to be of type `a -> b`, you can not define `fmap` on a subset of the possibilities an `fmap` should support.

Comment: Got it. Can I use `mapSquare` in an `Applicative` instance for `(<*>)`?

Comment: @arryn: you can use your `mapSquare`, but you will need to fill in something for `((a -> b) -> a -> b)`. Note that you can not just use any implementation. It needs to satisfy the fact that `pure f <*> g` yields the same result as `f <$> g`.
`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to the question I meant to ask, rather than actually asked, since the way I put it is a bit ambiguous. 
First of all, I actually did mess up and mixed `(<*>)` with `fmap`, thanks @WillemVanOnsem for pointing that out.
So, what I really meant to do was this:

```
mapNil :: ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> ((a -> b) -> Nil a -> Nil b )
mapNil mapA f Nil = Nil

mapCons :: (forall b . ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> ((a -> b) -> t a -> t b))
        -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
        -> ((a -> b) -> Cons t a -> Cons t b)
mapCons mapT mapA f (Cons x consx) =  Cons (f x) (mapT mapA f consx)
```

And then...

```
mapSquare' :: (forall b . ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> ((a -> b) -> t a -> t b))
           -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
           -> ((a -> b) -> Square' t a -> Square' t b)
mapSquare' mapT mapA f (Zero xs) = Zero (mapT (mapT mapA) f xs) 
mapSquare' mapT mapA f (Succ xs) = Succ (mapSquare' (mapCons mapT) mapA f xs)
```

`t` is a type constructor of kind `* -> *`, so a map function on `t` (`mapT`) should take a map function on its argument (`mapA`) as a parameter. So I need both  `mapT` and `mapA`